# How to hide my username from the URL?

Tags: url, security

At my WordPress site, on every post (and comment) my DISPLAY NAME (author's name) appears, and it is fine. If a reader clicks that name then it shows the author page (blog page) with all the posts by this author.

Now, the problem is that it also displays the **username** (which is a hidden thing) in the URL at the end. So, how to hide that **username** from that URL, as it's a loophole and leads to hacking attempts?

If it's not possible, then what I can do to make the author's name non-clickable? Please keep in mind that I am a non-technical person, so share all the steps of any probable solution.

Comment: Is the _username_ not an important part of the URL? Is this not what determines which "about" page to display? Or is there also an _id_?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **about WordPress development**. This *may* be a better fit at the [WordPress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange website. Be sure to read their [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) before posting to make sure your question meets their requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it entails any hacking risks. But if you want, there is another good solution which i sometimes use: instead, you can redirect your users to another page - like an "About me" page, where you can tell more about yourself or provide more information about your posts, business, or whatever you want.

You can do this easily with just a few lines of code:

- Open functions.php file
- Copy and paste function:

  ```
   add_filter( 'author_link', 'redirect_link' );
   function redirect_link() {
   return home_url( 'about-us' );
   }
  ```
- Change the page in the 4th line to whatever page you want
- Save changes

Comment: Although presumably the "username" is still visible in the URL on the page before the user clicks it?

Comment: Thanks, @Evgeny Yudin for this suggestion and the steps. However, I've got a redirection plugin. So, I used it and the trick worked successfully.